# Setting up common properties to a set controls

Tags: c#, reusability

I'm inside a function that repaints certain controls inside a form, it is implemented as an extension method for the ControlCollection class like this:

```
void SetColorsCorrespondingToVisualStudioTheme(this Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
  foreach (var control in controls)
  {
  ...
```

Inside this method, the code that sets some GUI properties that are common to a set of controls:

```
  ...
    if (controlType == typeof(TreeView))
    {
      ((TreeView)control).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      ((TreeView)control).BackColor = EditorBackgroundColor;
      ((TreeView)control).ForeColor = FontColor;
      continue;
    }

    if (controlType == typeof(TextBox))
    {
      ((TextBox)control).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      ((TextBox)control).BackColor = EditorBackgroundColor;
      ((TextBox)control).ForeColor = FontColor;
    }
 ...
```

I'll like to know if there is a way refactor the code to be reused like:

```
    if (controlType == typeof(TreeView) || controlType == typeof(TextBox))
    {
      ((controlType)control).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      ((controlType)control).BackColor = EditorBackgroundColor;
      ((controlType)control).ForeColor = FontColor;
    }
```

The code above obviously doesn't work because controlType is a variable and not a type but the intention of what I'm trying to do is what matters. I've also tried:

```
((typeof(controlType))control).B...
```

The only option I can think of now is to create custom controls for the base types (TreeView, TextBox, etc,) and make all of them implement a common interface so I can use them interchangeably:

```
 ...
    if (controlType == typeof(TreeView) || controlType == typeof(TextBox))
    {
      //CustomControl() ñ 
      ICustomControl newControl = new CustomControl(control);      
      newControl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
      newControl.BackColor = EditorBackgroundColor;
      newControl.ForeColor = FontColor;
    }
...
    public class CustomTreeView : ICustomControl
    {
...
    public class CustomTextBox : ICustomControl
    {
...
    public interface ICustomControl
    {
       public BorderStyle BorderStyle {get; set;}
       public Color BackColor {get; set;}
       public Color ForeColor {get; set;}
...
```

but that (at least in my head) sounds worse than keeping the multiple if's.
am I missing another approach you may know to solve this problem?

Comment: You could cast the `control` as `dynamic` and set whatever you want, as long as those properties exist at runtime. Ex: `((dynamic)control).Whatever = something;`.

Comment: These are properties that both classes inherit from the Control class.  So you can simply cast to (Control).

Comment: I believe BorderStyle is not part of the Control class though.

Comment: @Saragis Indeed, BorderStyle is not, that's why I need to cast the control to a more specific type.

Comment: @Ron Beyer your solution is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: `((controlType.GetType())control).BackColor = ...`?

Comment: @ragerory that won't work since controlType is a Type variable that contains the type of the control, its type is "Type".

Answer (score 1):

```
if (control is TreeView || control is TextBox)
{
  ((Control)control).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
  ((Control)control).BackColor = EditorBackgroundColor;
  ((Control)control).ForeColor = FontColor;
}
```

Comment: That's an improvement for the if clauses, but I want to also reuse the content of the if statement.

Comment: try it now, i'm not so used to this API though so i dunno for sure, just trying a base class they both share.

Comment: Also could i see how you are declaring control?

Comment: I´ve included the code where I declare "control" just now, it lives inside a foreach statement for a ControlCollection.

Although BorderStyle is not part of the Control Class your solution brings me a step forward in the right direction since a bunch of other controls I have use BackColor and ForeColor properties.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a struct to keep the desired values for the properties, and a method that takes a parameter of type Control and apply the style on it:

```
struct ThemeStyle
{
    ThemeStyle(Color backColor, Color foreColor, BorderStyle borderStyle)
    {
        this.BackColor = backColor;
        this.ForeColor = foreColor;
        this.BorderStyle = borderStyle;
    }
    public Color BackColor {get; private set;}
    public Color ForeColor {get; private set;}
    public BorderStyle BorderStyle {get; private set;}

    public void Apply(Control c)
    {
        c.BackColor = this.BackColor;
        switch(typeof(c))
        {
             case typeof(TreeView):
             case typeof(TextBox):
               c.BorderStyle = this.BorderStyle;
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** this code is only a demonstration, written directly here using a cellphone. There might be some mistakes.

Then in your loop all you need to do is call the Apply method with the control.

Comment: Though this seems like a good suggestion to group and sort the controls which share common properties, the problem is still to set those properties when some of these controls do not derive directly from the Control class (like BorderStyle), I could probably mix your approach with the suggestion made by @Ron Beyer (to use dynamic types) to have a complete solution. Thanks!

Comment: The point of this answer is moving the properties assignment outside of the loop and into a single method. Anyway, glad to help...