# C# saving colours of many things

Tags: c#, colors, picker

I have managed to get a colour-picker on the go which works, but I want to be able to save the colours the user wants. I have made links to the colordialog for labels/comboboxes/other controls as seperate items which works, but I would like to know how to save them (maybe to a txt file or something) as when the program restarts, it reverts back to black and white.

Thing is, it's not just 1 or 2 colour changes, I have got 35 labels, 7 comboboxes, 4 radiobuttons, 5 tabpages, 22 textboxes (text & background of each), 10 buttons (text and background of each) and A LOT of numericupdowns (text and background of each) - I have just spent the last hour sorting each one with the colour-picker...I don't want to have to do something to each thing in turn if I can help it...is there a way, or am I going to have to go through them all :)

Comment: A text format like this _label1=255*0*0 CRLF comboBox1=0*255*225_, oneline for each Control name (followed by R*G*B) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the process of saving the colors on form closing, loading the colors on the form load, then applying the default colors after they have loaded.
I store the settings into a global variable inside of the form so I can reference them by name.
Settings Variable:

```
 public Dictionary<string, FieldColor> colorSettings = new Dictionary<string, FieldColor>();
```

I use this following structure because you currently have two colors, but you could add more properties should the need arise.
Data Structure:

```
 public struct FieldColor
{
    public Color BackColor;
    public Color ForeColor;
    public FieldColor(Color backColor, Color foreColor)
    {
        this.BackColor = backColor;
        this.ForeColor = foreColor;
    }
}
```

The save method iterates through each control, then iterates through it's children controls, and if the color isn't the form's default color it saves the line.  This saves it as a csv.
Save:

```
public void SaveFieldColors(Control parent, StreamWriter colorWriter)
    {
        foreach (Control currentControl in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (currentControl.ForeColor != DefaultForeColor || currentControl.BackColor != DefaultBackColor)
            {
                //Save the file in your format
                colorWriter.WriteLine(currentControl.Name + "," + currentControl.BackColor.ToArgb() + "," + currentControl.ForeColor.ToArgb());
            }
            ApplyDefaultColorToControls(currentControl);
        }
    }
```

To load the settings I just break each line into a entry into the colorSettings dictionary.
Load:

```
 public void LoadFieldColors(StreamReader colorReader)
    {
        while (colorReader.EndOfStream == false)
        {
            //Read the file from your format
            string line = colorReader.ReadLine();
            string[] fieldData = line.Split(',');
            colorSettings.Add(fieldData[0], new FieldColor(Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(fieldData[1])), Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(fieldData[2]))));
        }
    }
```

Here I iterate through each control and their children to apply the formatting if there's an entry for that control's name.  If there isn't one I just set it to the default.
Apply the Formatting:

```
        public void ApplyDefaultColorToControls(Control parent)
        {
            foreach (Control currentControl in parent.Controls)
            {
               if (colorSettings.ContainsKey(currentControl.Name) == true)
               {
                //Set the controls settings equal to their color in your stored dictionary
                currentControl.BackColor = colorSettings[currentControl.Name].BackColor;
                currentControl.ForeColor = colorSettings[currentControl.Name].ForeColor;
               }
               else
               {
                //Set the control settings equal to default settings
                currentControl.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
                currentControl.ForeColor = DefaultForeColor;
               }
            ApplyDefaultColorToControls(currentControl);
        }
    }
```

Example Calls from the form events:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader settingsReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\path\to\file\filename.ending"))
        {
            LoadFieldColors(settingsReader);
        }
        ApplyDefaultColorToControls(this);
    }
           private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter settingsWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\path\to\file\filename.ending"))
        {
            SaveFieldColors(this, settingsWriter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi - it is a windows form. I suppose I should say I am a noob when it comes to this sort of thing and most of the comments are completely lost on me lol

Comment: Updated it using a windows Forms example.

Comment: Im going to have to have a good look at that tomorrow...a bit complex for this time of night haha. Thanks

Comment: I wasn't sure what info would be too much or too little so I went towards the excess side.

Comment: Well, your effort is much appreciated. I have put your code into my project, but it still doesn't save any colours...I have put `@"C:/BMW/Colours.txt"` where you said to put the filename. Or does it need to be in a specific format...I know you mentioned csv earlier in your post?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to store data in c#, starting with a simple text file and ending in databases... this is too broad. However you choose to save the data, I suggest to start with a `Dictonary<string, Touple<color, color>>` where the string is the control name, one is the backColor and the other is the foreColor and serialize it into a file (xml or json, doesn't matter all that much).
When you load your form, use a recursive function on 
 this.Controls to change the colors for each control.

Comment: [Also, read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251750/setting-up-common-properties-to-a-set-controls/31252782#31252782)

Comment: Thanks for that. Today I managed to get the colours to write to a txt file called "Colours.txt". It writes it like "Text Color [Blue]" (for text) then the next line is for background and writes it in the same way. Now I just need a way to get these into the program at startup...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if it is for WinForms project.
Create class for your settings :

```
[Serializable]
sealed class Settings
{
    internal Dictionary<string, Color> ForeColors { get; set; }
    internal Dictionary<string, Color> BackColors { get; set; }

    internal Settings()
    {
        ForeColors = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
        BackColors = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
    }

    internal void Save(string fileName = @"settings.ini")
    {
        using (FileStream stream = File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + fileName))
        {
            BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
        }
    }

    internal static Settings Load(string fileName = @"settings.ini")
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + fileName)) return null;
        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + fileName))
        {
            BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Settings;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your windows form subscribe to Form_Load Form_Closing events and add handlers:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Settings s = Settings.Load();
        if (s == null) return;
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            item.ForeColor = s.ForeColors[item.Name];
            item.BackColor = s.BackColors[item.Name];
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings s = new Settings();
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            s.ForeColors.Add(item.Name, item.ForeColor);
            s.BackColors.Add(item.Name, item.BackColor);
        }
        s.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Nice, though I would create a struct to keep styling options (ForeColor, BackColor) and have inside a method that receives the control and apply the style. ([see my answer to a similar question a while back](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31252782/3094533)) Then in your Settings class you only need to keep one dictionary, and of course, you can add an ApplySettings method to the settings object that will iterate the controls inside.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I just wanted to show the main idea but not best possible implementation.

Comment: I'm not so sure my suggestion is the best possible implementation... I just suggested what I believe is an improvement you your answer, take it or leave it, it's up to you and the OP...

Comment: @ZoharPeled //"method that receives the control(object) and apply the style"//  that idea came to my mind too but i dislike the fact that we pass Control object as parameter to some instance of struct (or class). This is not a very good thing to do imo. It's better when only windows form is allowed to do work with windows form controls.

Comment: It's a valid point, but then you have to write the apply theme logic in a base form, or in any form in your application. perhaps adding an extension method to Form would be better.

Comment: If configuration must be shared between different users, mostly the case of applications located on network drive, the "Settings" class is not the approriate soltion : config must be stored on a network file.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have tried to use this, but it doesn't save the settings.ini file and therefore doesn't save the colours. Do I have to put something in a button?